# cannot find node js module mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-modules

when i enter npm start in the cmd i got that error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'mysql'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\fmanagement\db_mysql\dbconnection.js:1:75)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! fmanagement@1.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the fmanagement@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Flavio Luiz\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-08-16T23_51_52_867Z-debug.log

after that im install mysql with

```
npm install -g mysql
```

and that is my dbconnection.js:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
```

var connection=mysql.createPool({

host:'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/',
 user:'root',
 password:'',
 database:'fmanagement'

});

module.exports=connection;

im newbie with node js. im doing something wrong?

Comment: try `npm i --save-dev mysql` this'll save the mysql in your dev dependencies in your package.json file. Once you do that restart your server and try again to see if it works.

Comment: nice man. Simple answer and works. Thank you. o/

Comment: Please use npm i -s mysql.Because --save-dev will only save in devdependencies of package.json